# switch image from plus to minus when user clicks image

Tags: jquery, image

At this site http://www.stephencarlwillis.com you will see two images after clicking "hide" to hide the video.

The images are a plus and minus sign. The default for the images should be a plus sign which would indicate to the user to expand when clicked. Then the images show a minus sign after they are clicked.

What I cannot figure out is how to make the image go back to the plus image after the user clicks the image a second time that way the image toggles back and forth from plus to minus.

Here is the example of the code I have to make the image switch, but cannot get image to switch back to plus sign.

```
$('#leftcolumn').hide();
$('#2d').hide();
$('#development').hide();
$('#right').hide();
$('#right2').hide();

$(function() {
$('.img2').click(function(){
$(".img2").attr('src',"assets/images/close.png");
$('#right2').toggle("fast");
$('#development').toggle("fade");
return false;
});
});
```

Here is the code I am testing to try and switch or toggle between the plus and minus images.

```
$(function() {
$('.img1').click(function() {
$('#right').toggle("fast");

if ($('.img1').is(':visible')) {
  $(this).attr('src',"assets/images/close.png");
 }else{
  $(this).attr('src',"assets/images/open.png");
 }
});
});
```

Here is the html for the jquery.

```
 <div id="leftcolumn"> 
 <h1>Stephen Carl Willis:<br> 
 Web Developer/Designer</h1> 

<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/open.png" alt="2d" class="img1">2D</>
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/open.png"     alt="2d"class="img2">Development</>

<div id="right">
<div id="2d">
2D graphic design coming soon.
</div><!--2d-->
</div>
<div id="right2">
<div id="development">
<p>Development portfolio coming soon.</p>
</div>
</div> 


</div>
```

Thank you for all your help. I have been trying to figure this out for a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/V8jCc/)**

this will work only in jquery version below 1.9.1

```
$('.img2').toggle(
  function(){ $(this).attr("src", "assets/images/close.png"); },
  function(){ $(this).attr("src", "assets/images/open.png"); }
);
```

TRY this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var open=true;    
  $('.img2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
        return oldSrc == 'assets/images/close.png' ? 'assets/images/open.png' : 'assets/images/close.png';
    });
      
      if(open==true)
       {
          // do what you want

            open=false;
       }
       else
       {
        // do what you want

            open=true;
       }

   });
});
```

new edited **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/V8jCc/2/)**

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: what jquery version ar you using

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: maybe I did not implement the code right. I removed the first jquery function with .img2 and replaced it with yours. It did not make any change.

Comment: **this will work only in jquery version below 1.9.1** You are using 1.10.2 Stephen.

Comment: because they have removed toggle with two function

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thank you. This does not work if I try to put it all together to toggle the dive then fade out.

Comment: you can do it in here itself. do you want me to edit the code for that

Comment: Ok try this ok, i found it doesnot toggle. now it does

Comment: oh right, almost there. Now the div will expand and turn to the minus pic but when you click the image again only the pic will switch to plus and the div will remain.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just changed open=false to open=true. It works perfect!