# how to shorten this jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I need to do this for every picture that expands or link, how can I say combine this statement using five different classes. Ex. .img1, .img2, .img3, .img4, .img5
Instead of repeating this function for every class, I would like to combine them all if possible.
Checkout the plus picture links at the top of my site to see what I am talking about.
http://www.stephencarlwillis.com
In order to understand please see this link first with my first question.
[switch image from plus to minus when user clicks image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550739/switch-image-from-plus-to-minus-when-user-clicks-image)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var open = true;
    $('.img2').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', function (i, oldSrc) {
            return oldSrc == 'assets/images/close.png' ? 'assets/images/open.png' : 'assets/images/close.png';
        });

        if (open == true) {
            $('#right2').toggle("fast");
            $('#development').toggle("fade");

            open = true;
        } else {
            return false;

            open = false;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding another class for each image, for example : "imgPlus" and then:
$('.imgPlus').click(function...........

Answer (score 0):

Just add another class to the images..

Ie....   .images

Then just add that as your click handler.